# Movable apps restricted to be moved to SD card by manufacturer

Tags: external-sd

I'm a user of the RealmeC2 and really want to move an app to the sd card.The creator of the app allows it to be moved but my phone's manufacturer does not. Is there any software that can send these apps to the sd card? I'm talking about those apps where we are supposed to enable usb debugging and let them do their thing? Even powershell commands will work.Please help me! This is a new device and i really don't want to root this just because i wanted to send an app to the sd card.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add screenshots of the missing change storage button in app settings storage, and the missing migrate data button in adoptable storage settings, to clarify for others (equivalents of https://www.jimcofer.com/personal/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Screenshot_2016-03-09-10-52-26.png and https://www.jimcofer.com/personal/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Screenshot_2016-03-09-10-50-00.png according to your ROM)

Comment: @alecxs updated my post!

Comment: wait some days i guess you're on the right way (trigger the missing "migrate data" button from adb shell commands)

Comment: i didn't get it to work, but it must be something like `adb am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageWizardMigrateProgress`

Comment: @alecxs i'm kinda in a rush to get this done! Either this or the root. Did i tell you about a problem i faced by the link you gave me? The bootimage doesn't want to get modified for some reason. It says image is unrecognized

Comment: It is a very new device, i guess you can not root at the moment. open a new question about how to decrypt Oppo boot.img and patch with Magisk https://bkerler.github.io/reversing/2019/04/24/the-game-begins

Comment: @alecxs by the way, i've used a micro sd  HC1 class 4 from sandisk! Do you think i'll have better luck if i try using a faster card??

Comment: @alecxs and also, i don't think it will ever be possible to root this device as this is an entry smartphone(Really cheap)

Comment: here comes the root solution https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/guide-root-realme-c2-unlock-bootloader-t3970447